# Check the return of a function defined in a class.vb from an .aspx.vb form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

it is really weird that I couldn't find anything that talks about the title. My problem is I have a `class1.vb` file which has a `Function read`. The function basically recieves a `string ByVal` from my `Reading.aspx.vb` which is basically a text. Then it reads that text and searches for a word. If the word "sea" is found, then `Function read Returns a  MsgBox("found")`.

In my `Reading.aspx.vb`, the text string is passed from my `Reading.aspx.vb` code by calling the function through:

**Read.aspx.vb**

```
 Dim rd as new class1
 rd.read(txtString)
```

**class1.vb**

```
>  Public Function Read(ByVal value1 As String)
```

code reading goes here and searching for the word `sea`

If the word `sea` is found then 
`Function Read` returns `Found` otherwise return `Not found`.

My issue is how can I determine what is the return of the `Function Read` from my `Read1.aspx.vb` form. Because what I am planning to make is that from my `Read.aspx.vb` form check what `Function read` returns. If it returns `found` then stop looping through other text files and if it returns `Not found` then continue the loop which is defined in `Read.aspx.vb`. So my question is how can I determine the return value of my `Class1.vb Function Read()` from my `Read.aspx.vb` form and act accordingly. Any thoughts or suggestions ?

Comment: Are you returning something from function?? or the messagebox is some ind of function which is used called and nothing is returned from function

Comment: @RohithNair No the only thing I am returning from the function is that message. That is so I can know that "ok I did not find the word `sea` in that segment of text, then I will pass a different segment. But I need to know what is the return message `found or not found` from my `Read.aspx.vb`.

Comment: private Function FnName(argList) As Return Type ... End Function . This will return the required type and you can assign it to a variable and check; right?

Comment: The Read function signature shouldn't be `Public Function Read(ByVal value1 As String) As String`?

Comment: @MarcusVinicius ok, but what I want to write in my `Read.aspx.vb` is that if `rd.read returns "not found"` then do something and vice versa. IS that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understand from your question, you have something like this:

```
Public Class Test
    Public Function Read(ByVal value As String) As String
        If (value.Contains("sea")) Then
            Return "Found"
        End If

        Return "Not Found"
    End Function        
End Class
```

So, all you have to do is.

```
If (rd.Read("Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet sea Lorem") = "Found") Then
    DoSomethingWhenFound()
Else
    DoSomethingWhenNotFound()
End If
```

Haven't you tried this?

Comment: I was thinking about it, thought I had to do it in a different way, tried it now, had some mistakes, It worked.

Comment: Might be advisable to return TRUE/FALSE as opposed to "Found" "Not Found" because "Found" is NOT the same as "found" because of letter case(upper/lower)...
just change the function declaration to:
Public Function Read(ByVal value As String) As Boolean and return True or False instead of "Found" "Not Found"

Comment: Yes @ZafKhan a boolean return would be preferable.